# Installing FMS on x86_64,fedora

Tags: linux, installation, x86-64, flash-media-server

When I follow the steps installing [FMS 3.0.5](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashmediaserver/update) on linux, get this error:

```
[root@server FMS_3_0_5_r601]# ./installFMS 

ERROR: Your architecture, \'x86_64\', is not supported by the
       Adobe Flash Media Server installer.

[root@server FMS_3_0_5_r601]#
```

Anyone managed to install it on **x86_64 linux** so far?

Answer (score 0):

In adobe doc written: **Flash Media Server will not install on Linux AS x86_64, only 
i386.**

Comment: Can you cite the reference here?